# Passing columns to user defined functions SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I have a table which has like 40-50 columns, all varchar, and I want to trim and do some cleansing in them according to the data in them. (Some columns may have numeric and date data).

I was too lazy to write down individual updates for each of the columns, so I have created a user defined function.

I pass a column name to it and an Identifier (DataType) - it returns to me the 'Enriched' Value.

So in a single update, I write

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET
column1 = function(column1, datatype)
column2 = function(column2, datatype)
WHERE <my filter condition>.
```

However, this is slow. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Here's the function:

```
    create function [dbo].[fn_Polaris_EnrichColumnToTargetDatatype] 
    (@ColumnName varchar(max), @Datatype varchar(max))
    returns varchar(max)
Begin
    Declare @EnrichedValue varchar(max);
    select @EnrichedValue = LTRIM(RTRIM(@ColumnName));

    if(@Datatype in ('Numeric', 'Decimal')) 
        BEGIN
            select @EnrichedValue = Replace(@EnrichedValue,',','');
            select @EnrichedValue = REPLACE(@EnrichedValue,'*','');
            select @EnrichedValue = REPLACE(@EnrichedValue,'$','');

            if (@EnrichedValue = '-' or len(@EnrichedValue) = 0 or @EnrichedValue is null or @EnrichedValue like '%[eE]%')
                begin
                    select @EnrichedValue = '0'
                end
            return @EnrichedValue
        END
    if(@Datatype in ('String', 'Varchar'))
        BEGIN
            select @EnrichedValue = REPLACE(@EnrichedValue, '"', '');
            return @EnrichedValue
        END
    return @EnrichedValue;
end
```